# Echo to file clashes with mailutils

Tags: echo

After installing ssmtp and **mailutils**, writing to a file with 'echo' tries to send me an email to username@hostname. For example:

Sending mail with mailutils:

`echo "Body text here." | mail -s "Subject text here." sendto@email.com`

and I use:
`echo "log content" > logfile.txt`
to write content to a log file.

The problem is that when I want to wite to a log file, I get an deliverable email from Gmail saying username@hostname is unreachable, meaning that it interferes with mailutils.

I this a known issue with mailutils which needs a workaround or fix and how can I approach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you doing something like this?

```
echo "log content" > logfile.txt | mail -s "Subject text" sendto@email.com
```

If so, it's no wonder that it won't work - you're already redirecting `echo`'s output to a file, you can't also pipe it to `mail` without using a program like `tee`.

`tee`'s entire purpose is to (from the man page):

> tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

Note: if you want to append to `logfile.txt` rather than overwrite it completely, use `tee -a logfile.txt`.  See `man tee`.

So, to save to a logfile AND pipe into mail, try this:

```
echo "log content" | tee logfile.txt | mail -s "Subject text" sendto@email.com
```

Alternatively, you can redirect to a logfile and then use `<` to redirect `mail`'s stdin to be the logfile, like so:

```
echo "log content" > logfile.txt
mail -s "Subject text" sendto@email.com < logfile.txt
```

Comment: I'm not. The two commands mentioned above are used in completely different instances. In the meantime I've also realised that it isn't mailutils causing the clash as I've uninstalled it and I still get the same problem when running `echo "log content" > logfile.txt`.

Comment: do you have some process monitoring that logfile and sending mail when it gets updated?  or a shell script or function or alias called `echo` that overrides the built-in `echo` or `/bin/echo`?  because neither of them send any email - they do not even have the capability to do so...that is not their job, their job is to echo their command line arguments to stdout, and nothing more.

Comment: No processes monitoring the logfiles. That was the original idea, but I started to use SMSs instead. I've never worked with aliases. Is there a way to check whether I accidentally could have done so? This is my email 'X-Google-Original-From: user@hostname
Received: by hostname (sSMTP sendmail emulation); Thu, 17 Mar 2016 16:08:03 +0200
Date:...
To: user
Subject: Cron <user@hostname> sudo /home/Scripts/logging_script.sh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=user>'

Comment: Can `base_dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
` somehow interfere? for example if `echo "log content" > $base_dir/logfile.txt`?

Comment: you should have included that email in the original question, it's essential information for diagnosis (whereas the speculations about `echo` and `mailutils` were just irrelevant distractions).  It looks like you have a cron job sending the email.  BTW, is `user@hostname` literal or have you edited it for anonymity?  Check "user"'s crontab, and the script mentioned in the error message - `/home/Scripts/logging_script.sh`.  as for your base_dir question, no.

Comment: Yes it is run through cron and user is for anonymity. What you're saying is completely right and was part of my initial diagnostics. The logging_script the email refers to writes two sequential dates (5 mins apart) to the log file (to ultimately determine power breaks). I can see no reason why this fairly short script (and other similar logging scripts through cron) will try to send an email (included below). From the email the "log content" is used in the body and the cron command (i.e. sudo /home/logging_script.sh) is used as "Subject text". "user" is used as sendto@email.com.

Comment: My apologies. Trying to send the code mentioned, but it's a mess with the comment system. Looking at the similarities of the logging scripts - they all have a few informative echos before the log writing event. It may be that for example `echo "log content"` followed by `echo "log content" > logfile.txt` might trigger this behaviour?

Comment: Also, just for in case, the log files are getting written correctly even if it tries to send the email.

Comment: To answer my own question, removing the 'informative echos' before the writing event resolved the issue. Any idea why or should I try to ask this as a separate question?

Comment: 1. you don't add scripts or command output in comments. you edit your question and add the information there, and format it correctly.  2. `cron` always emails any job output to the owner of the crontab or the address in the `MAILTO` variable, unless that output is redirected to a file (it's not unusual to redirect individual crontab entries to /dev/null) - see `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: I've learnt something. Thank you! Will also edit my question in the future, thanks. There was nothing set to send email, but I've added MAILTO="" to crontab -e. I suppose it got hold of my gmail account setting after installing and setting up SSMTP.